# Building Flex with Nant?

Tags: apache-flex, ant, nant, mxmlc, build-script

I'm wondering if I'm barking up the wrong tree here.  Is it possible to replace an Ant build script used for building Flex projects with a Nant build script?

Specifically, it doesn't seem like there are any replacements for the Ant `<mxmlc>`, `<macrodef>` and `<taskdef>` tasks provided with Nant or Nant-contrib.

I'm not too experienced in either Nant or Ant, so I'm wondering if I should keep investigating this.  Other than some sketchy looking replacement for `<macrodef>`, I really can't find anything on the tubes about what I'm trying to do here.  Our script is relatively small and straightforward, and I would love to remove the JRE and ant stuff from our build server if possible.

Has anyone built Flex with Nant before?

Comment: We have been building it with Nant for couple of years, using exec task to call mxmlc.exe. I don't see any problem with it, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We just used ANT as it was easier, but you can call the command line versions of MXMLC for compilation rather than relying on the tasks do work it out for you.

Your syntax will be very different, but its how ANT used to have to deal with it until the tasks library came along.

Comment: Thanks very much for the comment.  If I do have to go to the command line, I think I'll skip Nant altogether and just write an MSBuild task for it.

Answer (score 2):

+1 to writing an MSBuild task.  It'll hurt less in the long term.  I don't believe that the Flex Ant tasks are very complex.